# Split by character and align right in css

Tags: css, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist in asp.net

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMobile" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Samsung - 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Ball - 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Motorolaaaa - 3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Opppoooooooooooooo - 4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5">iphone - 5</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="6">nokiaaaa - 6</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

It's output is

[image: output]

But my requirement is like that if possible in CSS:

[image: desired ouput]

Thanks

Comment: Can't be done inside a <select> dropdown list. There is very little in regards to styling and design you can do which is why there are so many select box jquery plugins available. Most of these duplicate your dropdown  and recreate it using a <ul> unordered list.

Comment: @partypete25: Thanks for the reply but i can't use the jquery plugins.

Comment: @cameronjonesweb: Thanks to edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

I have not implemented it but it can work.

You can add spaces between your List Item. But you will need to count it how may spaces required.

You can use this character `&nbsp;` or `&#160;` for adding space.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMobile" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Samsung &nbsp;&nbsp; - 1</asp:ListItem>
```

If you are binding data from code behind you can use [`String.PadRight Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright.aspx) to add space

I am not sure but this fiddle is **near to your requirement**.

https://jsfiddle.net/KrShekhar/po1LpsaL/2/

The issue is the length of each character in pixel is not fixed. What you can do is put the text in a span and then calculate the with of the span and change the fiddle accordingly.

Comment: I cannot edit the code either i have to do it by CSS or Jquery.

Comment: @LokeshMasih so have you tried anything in jquery. If yest then put that code in your question.

Comment: I also tried that logic with proper space count in jquery but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMobile" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Samsung <span>- 1</span></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Ball <span>- 2</span></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Motorolaaaa <span>- 3</span></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Opppoooooooooooooo <span>- 4</span></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5">iphone <span>- 5</span></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="6">nokiaaaa <span>- 6</span></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<style>
#ddlMobile span{
float:left;
}
</style>
```